# Have incremental local perforce scls similar to git for a single file

Tags: perforce

Consider i have a file called `developers.txt`
What i want to do is (and i could do it in `git` neatly)
have 3-4 commits, each adding 1 line per commit

```
commit 2ad54bfe954006bafcb209f06ac0c12091d297c8 (HEAD -> main)
Author: Anuraag <anuraag@something.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 1 15:04:57 2023 +0530

    author #3 added

developers.txt

commit 26cabf7fa07154b19deff41c5cbb07bf0782bde7
Author: Anuraag <anuraag@something.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 1 15:04:43 2023 +0530

    author #2 added

developers.txt

commit d9e57385b505e2e02a8dc6064466c3974f22e66d
Author: Anuraag <anuraag@something.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 1 15:04:23 2023 +0530

    author #1 added

developers.txt

commit 03e7f4abddfa26b4b0518994c81e0a724ba1a778
Author: Anuraag <anuraag@something.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 1 15:03:56 2023 +0530

    adds heading

developers.txt
```

```
% cat developers.txt 
Authors:
1. Arthur
2. Canon
3. Doyle
```

What i want to know is, is there such an incremental local workspace development method when using perforce?
I want to have `SCL#3` to be on top of `SCL#2`, `SCL#1` etc.. but each SCL will be for the same file, in this case `developers.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is just basic versioning and should behave similarly across any version control system.  Every version builds on the one before it.

```
C:\Perforce\test>echo Authors:>developers.txt

C:\Perforce\test>p4 add developers.txt
//stream/main/developers.txt#1 - opened for add

C:\Perforce\test>p4 submit -d "adds heading"
Submitting change 460.
Locking 1 files ...
add //stream/main/developers.txt#1
Change 460 submitted.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit developers.txt
//stream/main/developers.txt#1 - opened for edit

C:\Perforce\test>echo 1. Arthur>>developers.txt

C:\Perforce\test>p4 submit -d "author #1 added"
Submitting change 461.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //stream/main/developers.txt#2
Change 461 submitted.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit developers.txt
//stream/main/developers.txt#2 - opened for edit

C:\Perforce\test>echo 2. Conan>>developers.txt

C:\Perforce\test>p4 submit -d "author #2 added"
Submitting change 462.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //stream/main/developers.txt#3
Change 462 submitted.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit developers.txt
//stream/main/developers.txt#3 - opened for edit

C:\Perforce\test>echo 3. Doyle>>developers.txt

C:\Perforce\test>p4 submit -d "author #3 added"
Submitting change 463.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //stream/main/developers.txt#4
Change 463 submitted.
```

Now we have our `developers.txt` with 4 versions.  We can see that the head revision contains all 4 changes:

```
C:\Perforce\test>cat developers.txt
Authors:
1. Arthur
2. Conan
3. Doyle
```

We can see its history as a list of the changes made to it:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 filelog developers.txt
//stream/main/developers.txt
... #4 change 463 edit on 2023/06/01 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'author #3 added'
... #3 change 462 edit on 2023/06/01 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'author #2 added'
... #2 change 461 edit on 2023/06/01 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'author #1 added'
... #1 change 460 add on 2023/06/01 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'adds heading'
```

And we can `annotate` the file to see the content of the file in context of the history, i.e. which revision/changelist added each line of content:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 annotate developers.txt
//stream/main/developers.txt#4 - edit change 463 (text)
1: Authors:
2: 1. Arthur
3: 2. Conan
4: 3. Doyle

C:\Perforce\test>p4 annotate -c developers.txt
//stream/main/shelves/developers.txt#4 - edit change 463 (text)
460: Authors:
461: 1. Arthur
462: 2. Conan
463: 3. Doyle
```

Comment: But, i don't want to submit my changes to the main stream/repo.
Only want to have them on my local machine..
Like for git, i didn't do a git push after each commit right...

Comment: Create a local server with `p4 clone` and then all your submits are local.  When you `p4 push` they go to the shared server that you cloned from.  (Note: unless you have really bad connectivity, this is more hassle IMO than working against the shared server directly.  Perforce supports a git-like distributed mode, but its strengths are in the centralized model where you work in a branch on the shared server.)